# Access control across Spring-JavaFX server-client system

Tags: java, spring, javafx, client-server, access-control

I have a system which uses server-client architecture. Just as the title says, the server is implemented using Spring which provides RESTful web services, while the client is implemented using JavaFX.

We have placed basic access controls on both sides:

- Users need to register/login to have any access the application
- Users are given different access rights, which allows them the rights to access different contents. For example, administrators are given admin rights, and this gives them access to "/admin/....." contents.

While the basics are working fine, I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to make the client application show only menus and links that they have access to. For example, if a normal user logs in, they should not see the links which would bring them to the administrative contents.

I **do not** want to hard-core that inside the client; I want the server to tell me exactly which links are accessible by the user that is currently logged in.

What are some of the common ways to do this?

#### Update

I don't need extremely dynamic behavior, such as suddenly allowing or disallowing access because another client did something that caused a transaction to be committed which caused a chain reaction somewhere.

For my case, the access rights are pretty static. The changes happen mainly because there is a change in business logic. If this happens, I should only change the server codes, and the client should be able to respond to the change on its own. There should be no change to the client, unless there is also a change in UI. This will save me the trouble of going to X number of clients located everywhere to change the client JAR file.

I'll give an example of such change.

In a banking system, there are employees who sell investment products (i.e. investment consultant). The system only allows them to look at customers' investment details. One day, the bank decides that the investment consultants should also have access to bank account details, so that they can scan for potential customers.

This change should only be done at the server, because no actual features are implemented on the client. This could have been easily solved if the system uses a web interface, because the webpage is generated dynamically by the server. Unfortunately, I do not have this option as the client is a JavaFX application.

Answer (score 0):

Misread your question at first sorry. **Answer: IMO NO**. This is not a good idea or a standard thing to do IMO. Reason being is that there could be complex rules behind this list of links a user can access that could be ever changing from some state. For instance as a junior employee in a bank I can't access client accounts who have over 4 million dollars. One moment an account has 3 million dollars, the next second 5. I try do something in-between that in your JavaFX app and click on a Link, doesn't work.

You may say that's a bad example as you won't include dynamic links as for situations like this, instead users will just get an error if their operation failed. Then I put it to you this list becomes redundant because it would defeat the purpose of the server telling you what you have access to, this could just be put in a library somewhere, and included as a dependency in clients as to save them from needing to send a request to a server for a list which will never change.

But I feel like going down the path of externalising the rules into a library would put you on a path of creating a tight coupling between client and server, although there could definitely be valid use cases for doing that, it's something I would try and avoid.

Instead I would focus on creating meaningful roles, which are well understood by all developers and business people, and coding to those roles as you would intuitively expect.